# Ubuntu 17.04 stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 17.04 which is dual booted with Windows 10.most recently I installed Python package named "Python-tk". thereafter Ubuntu is not working properly.for example,the unity symbols got replaced by question mark symbol and the hard drives got unmounted

Start-Date: 2017-12-09  15:32:41
Commandline: apt-get install python3-tk
Requested-By: abhishek (1000)
Install: libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.26.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-control-center-data:amd64 (1:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.8.4-1ubuntu3, automatic), libgpgmepp6:amd64 (1.8.0-3ubuntu5, automatic), libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.8.4-1ubuntu3, automatic), gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), python3-olefile:amd64 (0.44-1, automatic), libcaribou0:amd64 (0.4.21-2, automatic), libcaribou-common:amd64 (0.4.21-2, automatic), gir1.2-clutter-1.0:amd64 (1.26.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1, automatic), libgjs0g:amd64 (1.50.1-1, automatic), blt:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3, automatic), libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), python3-asn1crypto:amd64 (0.22.0-1, automatic), perl-modules-5.26:amd64 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-geoclue-2.0:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu1, automatic), libmutter-1-0:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:amd64 (0.6.42-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), gcc-7-base:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3, automatic), libpython3.6:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), python3.6:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), gjs:amd64 (1.50.1-1, automatic), gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64 (1.8.4-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.26.1-3ubuntu3, automatic), mutter-common:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libxmlsec1-nss:amd64 (1.2.24-4, automatic), gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libperl5.26:amd64 (5.26.0-8ubuntu1, automatic), python3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1, automatic), libgdm1:amd64 (3.26.1-3ubuntu3, automatic), gir1.2-gck-1:amd64 (3.20.0-5.1ubuntu1, automatic), libsane1:amd64 (1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1, automatic), gir1.2-cogl-1.0:amd64 (1.22.2-2, automatic), gir1.2-gweather-3.0:amd64 (3.26.0-1, automatic), liborcus-0.12-0:amd64 (0.12.1-3build1, automatic), gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64 (3.26.1-1, automatic), libnss-myhostname:amd64 (234-2ubuntu12.1, automatic), libxcb-res0:amd64 (1.12-1ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-shell-common:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), gir1.2-gcr-3:amd64 (3.20.0-5.1ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-online-accounts:amd64 (3.26.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0:amd64 (0.99.6-1, automatic), tk8.6-blt2.5:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3, automatic), libwebpmux3:amd64 (0.6.0-3, automatic), libcolord-gtk1:amd64 (0.1.26-1.1, automatic), libxtables12:amd64 (1.6.1-2ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0:amd64 (3.24.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:amd64 (1.22.2-2, automatic), caribou:amd64 (0.4.21-2, automatic), gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 (1:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.3-0ubuntu1), libhunspell-1.6-0:amd64 (1.6.2-1, automatic), gnome-shell:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libmozjs-52-0:amd64 (52.3.1-0ubuntu3, automatic), gir1.2-polkit-1.0:amd64 (0.105-18, automatic), gir1.2-caribou-1.0:amd64 (0.4.21-2, automatic), libpoppler68:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1, automatic), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.40.18-1, automatic), libxmlsec1:amd64 (1.2.24-4, automatic), libgtop-2.0-11:amd64 (2.38.0-1, automatic), mutter:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic)
Upgrade: debconf:amd64 (1.5.59ubuntu1, 1.5.63), libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), perl-base:amd64 (5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1), libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-17, 0.105-18), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), network-manager-pptp:amd64 (1.2.4-2, 1.2.4-4), libnet-libidn-perl:amd64 (0.12.ds-2build3, 0.12.ds-2build4), hplip-data:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2, 3.17.7+repack0-3), libqgsttools-p1:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2ubuntu1~3, 5.9.1-3ubuntu1), dbus-x11:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu2, 1.10.22-1ubuntu1), gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1, 3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1), libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2build1~3, 5.9.1-2), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu2, 1.10.22-1ubuntu1), unity-schemas:amd64 (7.5.0+17.04.20170407.1-0ubuntu1, 7.5.0+17.10.20171010-0ubuntu1), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:17.04.8, 1:17.10.11), qml-module-qtquick-window2:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), python3-zope.interface:amd64 (4.3.2-1, 4.3.2-1build2), libgtop2-common:amd64 (2.34.2-1, 2.38.0-1), iptables:amd64 (1.6.0-3ubuntu2, 1.6.1-2ubuntu1), gnome-session-common:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.26.1-0ubuntu6), compiz-plugins-default:amd64 (1:0.9.13.1+17.04.20170109-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1), libnet-ssleay-perl:amd64 (1.80-1, 1.80-1build1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.10.0-40.44, 4.13.0-19.22), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.3, 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2), liblist-moreutils-perl:amd64 (0.416-1build2, 0.416-1build3), qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0:amd64 (0.1+16.04.20160329-0ubuntu3~1, 0.1+17.10.20170824-0ubuntu1), qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2, 3.17.7+repack0-3), qml-module-qtquick2:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), sane-utils:amd64 (1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4, 1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.26.1-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-gtk2:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), onboard-common:amd64 (1.4.1-0ubuntu1, 1.4.1-2ubuntu1), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.179, 3.186), libgoa-1.0-common:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.26.1-1ubuntu1), brasero-common:amd64 (3.12.1-4ubuntu1, 3.12.1-4ubuntu2), libqt5sensors5:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2build1~2, 5.9.1-2), libdecoration0:amd64 (1:0.9.13.1+17.04.20170109-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1), libgweather-3-6:amd64 (3.24.1-0ubuntu0.1, 3.26.0-1), libsystemd0:amd64 (232-21ubuntu7.1, 234-2ubuntu12.1), onboard:amd64 (1.4.1-0ubuntu1, 1.4.1-2ubuntu1), python3-systemd:amd64 (233-1, 234-1build1), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), gsettings-ubuntu-schemas:amd64 (0.0.7+17.04.20161109-0ubuntu1, 0.0.7+17.10.20170922-0ubuntu1), dbus:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu2, 1.10.22-1ubuntu1), debconf-i18n:amd64 (1.5.59ubuntu1, 1.5.63), libqt5multimedia5:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2ubuntu1~3, 5.9.1-3ubuntu1), libqt5organizer5:amd64 (5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu23~3, 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~3), libreoffice-gtk:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), language-selector-common:amd64 (0.176, 0.180.1), python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 (3.3.0-1, 3.4.0-3build1), libqt5contacts5:amd64 (5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu23~3, 5.0~git20140515~29475884-0ubuntu24~3), python3-gi-cairo:amd64 (3.22.0-2, 3.24.1-2build1), libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.78-2, 0.78-2build1), libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), python3-brlapi:amd64 (5.4-7ubuntu1, 5.4-7ubuntu4), python3-pil:amd64 (4.0.0-4, 4.1.1-3build2), libgdata22:amd64 (0.17.7-0ubuntu1, 0.17.9-1), libc6:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libuuid-perl:amd64 (0.27-1, 0.27-1build1), libmirclient-dev:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), liblocale-gettext-perl:amd64 (1.07-3build1, 1.07-3build2), qml-module-qtquick-layouts:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.24.2-0ubuntu0.1, 3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1), libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), python3:amd64 (3.5.3-1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2), libperlio-gzip-perl:amd64 (0.19-1build2, 0.19-1build3), libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-17, 0.105-18), qml-module-qttest:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libmircommon-dev:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), libip6tc0:amd64 (1.6.0-3ubuntu2, 1.6.1-2ubuntu1), locales:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), hud:amd64 (14.10+17.04.20170106.1-0ubuntu1, 14.10+17.10.20170619-0ubuntu1), rhythmbox-plugins:amd64 (3.4.1-2ubuntu1, 3.4.1-2ubuntu5), libnm0:amd64 (1.4.4-1ubuntu3.2, 1.8.4-1ubuntu3), python3-psutil:amd64 (5.0.1-1, 5.0.1-1build2), libmircookie2:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), network-manager-gnome:amd64 (1.4.2-1ubuntu4, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1), brasero-cdrkit:amd64 (3.12.1-4ubuntu1, 3.12.1-4ubuntu2), libmircore1:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), qmlscene:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), iio-sensor-proxy:amd64 (2.2-0ubuntu1, 2.2-1), network-manager:amd64 (1.4.4-1ubuntu3.2, 1.8.4-1ubuntu3), libmircore-dev:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), python3-uno:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), qml-module-qtqml-models2:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libpango-perl:amd64 (1.227-1build1, 1.227-2build1), python3-cups:amd64 (1.9.73-1, 1.9.73-1build2), libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libqt5quicktest5:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libfile-fcntllock-perl:amd64 (0.22-3build1, 0.22-3build2), libapt-pkg-perl:amd64 (0.1.30, 0.1.33), libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libqt5qml5:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), python3-renderpm:amd64 (3.3.0-1, 3.4.0-3build1), gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64 (3.4.1-2ubuntu1, 3.4.1-2ubuntu5), python3-pycurl:amd64 (7.43.0-2, 7.43.0-2build2), libreoffice-style-galaxy:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), python3-simplejson:amd64 (3.10.0-1, 3.11.1-1build1), libwayland-client0:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 1.14.0-1), libcairo-perl:amd64 (1.106-1build2, 1.106-2build1), rhythmbox-data:amd64 (3.4.1-2ubuntu1, 3.4.1-2ubuntu5), libwayland-bin:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 1.14.0-1), libiptc0:amd64 (1.6.0-3ubuntu2, 1.6.1-2ubuntu1), libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 (2.52.0-1, 2.54.1-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libqt5multimedia5-plugins:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2ubuntu1~3, 5.9.1-3ubuntu1), libsnmp30:amd64 (5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu5, 5.7.3+dfsg-1.7ubuntu1), python3-minimal:amd64 (3.5.3-1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2), libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.20.4-0ubuntu2, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1), libclone-perl:amd64 (0.38-2build1, 0.38-2build2), libwayland-dev:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 1.14.0-1), libapparmor-perl:amd64 (2.11.0-2ubuntu4, 2.11.0-2ubuntu17), libsub-name-perl:amd64 (0.21-1, 0.21-1build1), python3-cryptography:amd64 (1.7.1-2, 1.9-1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:17.04.10, 1:17.10.8), libc-bin:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), libmirprotobuf3:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:17.04.8, 1:17.10.11), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:17.04.10, 1:17.10.8), libnet-dbus-perl:amd64 (1.1.0-4build1, 1.1.0-4build2), libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.3-1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2), python3-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.9.1-2, 1.9.1-2build2), libmirclient9:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), libhpmud0:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2, 3.17.7+repack0-3), unity-services:amd64 (7.5.0+17.04.20170407.1-0ubuntu1, 7.5.0+17.10.20171010-0ubuntu1), python3-markupsafe:amd64 (0.23-3, 1.0-1build1), libqt5webkit5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-1build1~2, 5.9.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.52.0-1, 2.54.1-1ubuntu1), ure:amd64 (5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libdbus-1-dev:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu2, 1.10.22-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (232-21ubuntu7.1, 234-2ubuntu12.1), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libnma0:amd64 (1.4.2-1ubuntu4, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1), python3-yaml:amd64 (3.12-1, 3.12-1build2), libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.52.0-1, 2.54.1-1ubuntu1), compiz-gnome:amd64 (1:0.9.13.1+17.04.20170109-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1), libyaml-libyaml-perl:amd64 (0.63-2, 0.63-2build1), systemd:amd64 (232-21ubuntu7.1, 234-2ubuntu12.1), libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libgsettings-qt1:amd64 (0.1+16.04.20160329-0ubuntu3~1, 0.1+17.10.20170824-0ubuntu1), qtubuntu-desktop:amd64 (0.64+17.04.20170404-0ubuntu1, 0.64+17.10.20170707-0ubuntu3), libglib-perl:amd64 (3:1.324-1, 3:1.326-1build1), libcompizconfig0:amd64 (1:0.9.13.1+17.04.20170109-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1), libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 (0.105-17, 0.105-18), libio-pty-perl:amd64 (1:1.08-1.1build3, 1:1.08-1.1build4), python3-dbus:amd64 (1.2.4-1, 1.2.4-1build3), libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2, 3.17.7+repack0-3), gnome-session-bin:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.26.1-0ubuntu6), libnm-gtk0:amd64 (1.4.2-1ubuntu4, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1), libbrasero-media3-1:amd64 (3.12.1-4ubuntu1, 3.12.1-4ubuntu2), libsocket6-perl:amd64 (0.27-1build1, 0.27-1build2), libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), policykit-1:amd64 (0.105-17, 0.105-18), libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-3build1~3, 5.9.1-2), python3-cairo:amd64 (1.10.0+dfsg-5build1, 1.10.0+dfsg-5build3), librhythmbox-core10:amd64 (3.4.1-2ubuntu1, 3.4.1-2ubuntu5), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.24-9ubuntu2.2, 2.26-0ubuntu2), libsane-common:amd64 (1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4, 1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1), python3-gi:amd64 (3.22.0-2, 3.24.1-2build1), python3-crypto:amd64 (2.6.1-7, 2.6.1-7build2), pciutils:amd64 (1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu9, 1:3.5.2-1ubuntu1), perl:amd64 (5.24.1-2ubuntu1.1, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1), libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), uno-libs3:amd64 (5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.20.4-0ubuntu2, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-grilo-0.3:amd64 (0.3.3-1, 0.3.4-1), libreoffice-style-tango:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libxml-parser-perl:amd64 (2.44-2build2, 2.44-2build3), accountsservice:amd64 (0.6.42-0ubuntu2, 0.6.42-0ubuntu3.1), language-selector-gnome:amd64 (0.176, 0.180.1), libqt5network5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), libpci3:amd64 (1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu9, 1:3.5.2-1ubuntu1), libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), compiz-core:amd64 (1:0.9.13.1+17.04.20170109-0ubuntu1, 1:0.9.13.1+17.10.20170901-0ubuntu1), libqt5positioning5:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~1, 5.9.1+dfsg-2), libmircookie-dev:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 (1.7-5build5, 1.7-5build6), onboard-data:amd64 (1.4.1-0ubuntu1, 1.4.1-2ubuntu1), python3-lxml:amd64 (3.7.3-1, 4.0.0-1), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), libstdc++6:amd64 (6.3.0-12ubuntu2, 7.2.0-8ubuntu3), libip4tc0:amd64 (1.6.0-3ubuntu2, 1.6.1-2ubuntu1), qtdeclarative5-dev-tools:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7, 3.26.1-0ubuntu2.17.10.1), libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.72-3, 3.72-3build1), libqt5quick5:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 (0.04-4build2, 0.04-4build3), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.52.0-1, 2.54.1-1ubuntu1), libgtk2-perl:amd64 (2:1.2499-1, 2:1.24992-1build1), libmircommon7:amd64 (0.26.3+17.04.20170605-0ubuntu1, 0.28.0+17.10.20171011.1-0ubuntu1), libwayland-server0:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 1.14.0-1), libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1.17.04.1, 5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1), qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-3build1~2, 5.9.1-2), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), python3-apt:amd64 (1.4.0~beta2, 1.4.0~beta3build2), libaccountsservice0:amd64 (0.6.42-0ubuntu2, 0.6.42-0ubuntu3.1), libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:amd64 (1:5.3.1-0ubuntu2, 1:5.4.2-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), qml-module-qtqml-statemachine:amd64 (5.7.1-1ubuntu1~7, 5.9.1-4ubuntu1), rhythmbox:amd64 (3.4.1-2ubuntu1, 3.4.1-2ubuntu5), colord:amd64 (1.3.3-2, 1.3.3-2build1), libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 (0.04-7build6, 0.04-7.1), libwayland-cursor0:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 1.14.0-1)
Remove: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras0.2:amd64 (0.3+17.04.20170323-0ubuntu1), unity-control-center-faces:amd64 (15.04.0+17.04.20170402.6-0ubuntu1), qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), unity8:amd64 (8.15+17.04.20170404.7-0ubuntu3), gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.30.4-0ubuntu1), friendly-recovery:amd64 (0.2.35), unity-greeter-session-broadcast:amd64 (0.1+14.10.20140601-0ubuntu5), qtdeclarative5-qtmir-plugin:amd64 (0.5.1+17.04.20170404-0ubuntu2), brasero:amd64 (3.12.1-4ubuntu1), gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7), unity-webapps-common:amd64 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), unity8-desktop-session:amd64 (1.0.13+17.04.20170328.1-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-app-launch:amd64 (0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2), qtmir-desktop:amd64 (0.5.1+17.04.20170404-0ubuntu2), ubuntu-keyboard-data:amd64 (0.100+17.04.20170320-0ubuntu1), policykit-1-gnome:amd64 (0.105-6ubuntu2), snapd:amd64 (2.28.5+17.04), update-manager:amd64 (1:17.04.8), printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2), qml-module-ubuntu-settings-components:amd64 (0.12+17.04.20170118-0ubuntu1), gnome-software:amd64 (3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7), usb-creator-common:amd64 (0.3.3), libubuntu-app-launch4:amd64 (0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.379.1), ubuntu-session:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1), plainbox-provider-resource-generic:amd64 (0.23-1.1), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.379.1), indicator-transfer-download-manager:amd64 (0.2+17.04.20170215-0ubuntu2), xdiagnose:amd64 (3.8.5), unity8-private:amd64 (8.15+17.04.20170404.7-0ubuntu3), usb-creator-gtk:amd64 (0.3.3), libertine-xmir-tools:amd64 (1.7.1+17.04.20170331-0ubuntu1), unity:amd64 (7.5.0+17.04.20170407.1-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-printing-app:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170401-0ubuntu1), libcontent-hub0:amd64 (0.3+17.04.20170403-0ubuntu2), account-plugin-facebook:amd64 (0.13+17.04.20170314-0ubuntu1), packagekit-tools:amd64 (1.1.5-2ubuntu1), python3-plainbox:amd64 (0.25-1), checkbox-converged:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu3), unity-control-center:amd64 (15.04.0+17.04.20170402.6-0ubuntu1), gnome-disk-utility:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1), unity-greeter:amd64 (17.04.0-0ubuntu1), indicator-session:amd64 (17.3.20+17.04.20170403-0ubuntu1), nplan:amd64 (0.23~17.04.1), qml-module-ubuntu-web:amd64 (0.23+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1), content-hub:amd64 (0.3+17.04.20170403-0ubuntu2), ubuntu-terminal-app:amd64 (0.7.218+17.04.20170405.7-0ubuntu1), gnome-music:amd64 (3.24.1.1-0ubuntu1), nautilus-share:amd64 (0.7.3-2ubuntu2), webapp-container:amd64 (0.23+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1), unity-webapps-service:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu2), qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components:amd64 (0.12+17.04.20170118-0ubuntu1), udisks2:amd64 (2.1.8-1ubuntu1), gvfs-fuse:amd64 (1.30.4-0ubuntu1), nautilus:amd64 (1:3.20.4-0ubuntu2), qtubuntu-appmenutheme:amd64 (0.64+17.04.20170404-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.7), network-manager-openvpn:amd64 (1.2.6-2ubuntu1), hplip:amd64 (3.16.11+repack0-2), qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1:amd64 (0.3+17.04.20170403-0ubuntu2), plainbox-provider-checkbox:amd64 (0.25-2), ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts:amd64 (0.7+17.04.20170308.2-0ubuntu3), session-shortcuts:amd64 (1.2ubuntu0.17.04.1), libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 (7.5.0+17.04.20170407.1-0ubuntu1), brltty:amd64 (5.4-7ubuntu1), ubuntu-core-launcher:amd64 (2.28.5+17.04), unity-control-center-signon:amd64 (0.1.9+16.10.20160825-0ubuntu1), checkbox-gui:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu3), packagekit:amd64 (1.1.5-2ubuntu1), indicator-datetime:amd64 (15.10+17.04.20170322-0ubuntu2), rfkill:amd64 (0.5-1ubuntu3), qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), gvfs:amd64 (1.30.4-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:17.04.10), unity8-common:amd64 (8.15+17.04.20170404.7-0ubuntu3), libnss-resolve:amd64 (232-21ubuntu7.1), qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), libubuntutoolkit5:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), dbus-user-session:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu2), nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 (3.12.1-4ubuntu1), python3-checkbox-support:amd64 (0.22-1), webbrowser-app:amd64 (0.23+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1), gnome-system-log:amd64 (3.9.90-4), libubuntugestures5:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), sessioninstaller:amd64 (0.20+bzr150-0ubuntu4.1), network-manager-pptp-gnome:amd64 (1.2.4-2), ubuntu-system-settings:amd64 (0.4+17.04.20170324-0ubuntu1), update-notifier:amd64 (3.179), url-dispatcher:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2), gvfs-daemons:amd64 (1.30.4-0ubuntu1), libunity-webapps0:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu2), libsane:amd64 (1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4), url-dispatcher-tools:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2), qml-module-ubuntu-components-labs:amd64 (1.3.2190+17.04.20170327), unity-webapps-qml:amd64 (0.1+16.10.20160713-0ubuntu1), indicator-network:amd64 (0.9.0+17.04.20170322-0ubuntu1), qtubuntu-print:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2017-12-09  15:42:41

Start-Date: 2017-12-09  23:38:56
Commandline: apt-get install amd*
Requested-By: abhishek (1000)
Install: amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20160316.3)
End-Date: 2017-12-09  23:39:28

Start-Date: 2017-12-10  09:00:16
Commandline: apt-get remove amd*
Requested-By: abhishek (1000)
Remove: amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20160316.3)
End-Date: 2017-12-10  09:00:46

Start-Date: 2017-12-10  09:02:48
Commandline: apt-get install amd*
Requested-By: abhishek (1000)
Install: amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20160316.3)
End-Date: 2017-12-10  09:03:01strong text

Comment: Please locate the log of the install in /vat/log/apt, and edit your question to include the log's complete session for that install.

Comment: I believe user535733 meant to say `/var/log/apt` :)